# Return an IEnumerable<T> or List<T> from library

Tags: c#

I'm designing a library that connects to a data source (similar to a DB) and returns various POCO objects.

I'm using the datasource vendors .NET library to make the connection (and retrieve the objects), which I'm then converting into my much lighter POCO objects. To build these POCO objects, I have a static method on each POCO class (`.FromDBObject(DBObject obj)` that takes the DB object and returns a new POCO instance.

The initial connection to the DB isn't fast so it's not something I want to be doing on the fly (per POCO build), so I'm wrapping a library around it that manages the connection to limit this slowdown, as well as dispose of the connection correctly.

As part of this library, I have a number of methods that return lists of my POCO's. One 'oddity' of the DB objects is that they aren't loaded into memory when the vendor library loads them, they require an open connection to load their data.

As a result, if I return an `IEnumerable<POCO>` then it's possible that the connection could be closed (time/dispose) before this has been enumerated, thus crashing when creating the POCO's.

So a long set up for a short question.

1. Should I return `IEnumerable<POCO>` but in the actual method perform a `.ToList()` to force the instantiation or should I specify the return type as `List<POCO>`?

Comment: So the Library you're wrapping is returning IQueryable<T>?

Comment: No, the library I'm wrapping returns a vendor custom collection, which I then access and manipulate using LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method return type should have little bearing on your data access. Determine whether you want to return an `IEnumerable` or a `List` first. If `IEnumerable` is sufficient, then use a `ToList()`.

If you need the extra methods that `List` provides, then returning `List` is fine since it does an implicit `ToList()` call, although I would explicitly call `ToList()` anyway just to make it clear that you want load the data from the database at that point in the code.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I think the explicit 'ToList()' call is the safest option. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you must already force an eager evaluation of the query. You have two choices for the eager evaluation
1. ToList()
2. ToArray()

Pros and cons for returning an IList

If consumers frequently need the data in an IList format then you are saving an extra enumeration (since you are returning query.ToList() instead of query.ToArray().. if subscribers needed the list they would need to effectively call query.ToArray().ToList(), causing a double enumeration). The con is that changing your return type from ILIST to IEnumerable would be breaking.

Personally I would go with IEnumerable because it's making fewer assumptions. I assume if you really needed an IList method you could just add a special ListFromDBObject(DBOject obj) method